# Copiar valor de cada fila recorrida, y pegar n° veces en otra columna en VBA

Tags: excel, vba, bucle-for, macros

Quizás es algo super simple lo que pregunto, pero me he quedado pegado y no sé como avanzar.
A modo de ejemplo voy a plantear lo que tengo. Es una hoja de Excel donde posee años y los meses del año.

En datos poseo esta tabla.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W09l0.png)

Como estoy trabajando con datos grandes, busco optimizar esto de tal manera que al copiar el valor de la Columna (A2) Ej:'2008' , se copie y se pegue 'n' veces (En este caso 12, por el número de meses) en la columna (J) y en la columna (K) los meses. Y así vaya recorriendo cada fila de la columna (A).

El punto es que busco clasificar cada año, con su mes respectivo, o sea.. de esta manera:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlJPs.png)

Y mi código en VBA es el sigte:

```
   Sub Macro1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("B2").Select
    'RangeCount = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    recct = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    'recct guarda numero de replicaciones que se hace para los meses
    num = 0  
    
       Range("A2").Select
       For i = 2 To 14 'Recorre las filas de años
       Cells(i, 1).Copy
            If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
                For cont = 1 To recct  'Valor del numero de meses=12
                    Range("J" & cont).PasteSpecial
                Next cont
            End If
        
        Next i
    
   End Sub
```

Sé que algo falta en mi código, porque sólo me trae el valor del último mes, como en esta foto:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwQXl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estabas cerca, pero pegas todo el rato en el mismo sitio, sobreescribiendo. No actualizas la posición donde quieres escribir. Prueba así:

```
Sub macro()

Dim MatrizMeses As Variant
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long, ZZ As Long, MiPos As Long



LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'última fila con datos en columna A
MatrizMeses = Array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")

'creamos una matriz con índices de 0 a 11 con los meses, porque es una cantidad fija de datos. MatrizMeses(0) devolverá Enero, MAtrizMeses(1) devolverá Febrero,...
MiPos = 2 'empezamos a pegar los datos en la fila 2 de la columna J y K

For i = 2 To LR Step 1
    For ZZ = 0 To 11 Step 1
        Range("J" & MiPos).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        Range("K" & MiPos).Value = MatrizMeses(ZZ)
        MiPos = MiPos + 1 'incrementamos MiPos para escribir en la siguiente fila
    Next ZZ
Next i

Erase MatrizMeses 'borramos matriz

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias! , era lo que necesitaba.